# Como impedir que os elementos de uma div ultrapasse o pai?

Tags: div

Ola, gostaria de que minhas divs laterais nao ultrapasse o pai. A quantidade de divs dependerá de quantas informações tiver no banco (se tiver 10 supermercados, por exemplo, aparecerá 10 divs)

div pai: divOptions

divs filhas: .eachOptions

HTML:

```
<div id="divOptions" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                                                    <div class="eachOptions" id="op1">
                                                        <input class="radioBTN" type="radio" name="radioButton"
                                                        id="radioBTN1">
                                                        <p id="eachOptionsT">Supermercado BigBom</p>
                                                        <p id="eachOptionsP">R$ 10,85<p>
                                                        </div>  

                                                        <div class="eachOptions" id="op2">
                                                            <input class="radioBTN" type="radio" name="radioButton"
                                                            id="radioBTN2">
                                                            <p id="eachOptionsT">Supermercado Fonseca</p>
                                                            <p id="eachOptionsP">R$ 11,43<p>
                                                            </div>  

                                                            <div class="eachOptions" id="op3">
                                                                <input class="radioBTN" type="radio" name="radioButton"
                                                                id="radioBTN3">
                                                                <p id="eachOptionsT">Supermercado Sempre Vale</p>
                                                                <p id="eachOptionsP">R$ 12,30<p>
                                                                </div>  


                                                                <div class="eachOptions" id="op4">
                                                                    <input class="radioBTN" type="radio" name="radioButton"
                                                                    id="radioBTN4">
                                                                    <p id="eachOptionsT">Supermercado Unifae</p>
                                                                    <p id="eachOptionsP">R$ 89,50<p>
                                                                    </div>  
                                                                </div>
```

CSS PAI :

```
#divOptions {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
height: 400px;
```

}

CSS FILHO :

```
#modalProduto #allMarkets #options .eachOptions {
padding-left: 5px;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid red;
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tente dar uma olhada no flexbox creio que ele vá te ajudar https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que se você colocar um

> overflow-y: auto

na divOptions, resolverá o seu problema